# Destruir fragmento ao voltar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragment

Tenho um `NavigationDrawer` com muitos menus no `Navigation` todos abrem como fragmento, quando abro um fragmento e volto ele retorna para a tela inicial e se voltar novamente ele fechar, blz ta correto.

Mas se abrir um fragmento A pelo menu e quando esse fragmento A estiver aberto e escolher outro fragmento B ele vai abrir também, mas ao voltar ele não retorna para a tela inicial, ele retorna para o fragmento A e depois para a tela inicial.

Gostaria que independente do fragmento aberto e quando clicasse no botão voltar do celular ele retornasse para a tela inicial e depois ao voltar novamente ele fechar a aplicação.

código do `onNavigationItemSelected`

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_inicio) {
            meuFragmento = new principal();
            fragmentoSelec = true;
            barra = "Expresso1002";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_consultar_horarios) {
            meuFragmento = new consultarHorarios();
            fragmentoSelec = true;
            barra = "Horários e Preços";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_pontos_venda) {
            meuFragmento = new pontosVendas();
            fragmentoSelec = true;
            barra = "Pontos de Vendas";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_quem_somos) {
            meuFragmento = new quemSomos();
            fragmentoSelec = true;
            barra = "Quem Somos";
       } else if (id == R.id.nav_sair) {
            finish();
       }

       if (fragmentoSelec == true) {

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_principal, meuFragmento).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }

        toolbar.setTitle(barra);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Código do `onBackPressed`

```
public void onBackPressed() {

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //retornar o drawer
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            // retorna todos os fragments que estão em backStack
        } else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
                //Volta o titulo pra Activity
                toolbar.setTitle("Expresso1002");
            }
        }
        //fecha a aplicação, aqui você pode fazer voltar para alguma activity
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, é só limpar o BackStack, deixando onBackPressed da seguinte maneira:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    //retorna o drawer
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        // Independente do fragment que está, retorna pra activity
    } else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        //faz voltar pra activity e limpa o popBackStack
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
    //fecha a aplicação, aqui você pode fazer voltar para alguma activity
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**OPÇÃO:**

Caso estiver tendo problema com atualização dos títulos cria o método a seguir:

```
private void updateTitleAndDrawer(Fragment fragment) {
    String flagFragment = fragment.getClass().getName();

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        //Quando não tiver mais fragment em stack, o titulo da toolbar volta a ser da sua Activity
        toolbar.setTitle("Activity");

    } else if (flagFragment.equals(BlankFragment.class.getName())) {
        //titulo fragment1
        toolbar.setTitle("Fragment1");

    } else if (flagFragment.equals(BlankFragment2.class.getName())) {
        //titulo fragment2
        toolbar.setTitle("Fragment2");
    }
}
```

E no onCreate da sua activity adicione:

```
        //Sempre que o usuário inicia ou volta o fragmento esse Listener é chamado
        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
        //recupera o fragment a partir do id em que está no xml da sua activity.
                Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);

                if (fragment != null){
                    updateTitleAndDrawer(fragment);
                } else {
                    toolbar.setTitle("Activity");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Mano ficou Show, vlw.